# How to scroll down pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a pre HTML tag with a lot of code in it and with overflow: auto. How can I set the pre tag to be scrolled down (so the last line of the content is visible) with jquery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jQuery( function(){
   var pre = jQuery("#myPre");
    pre.scrollTop( pre.prop("scrollHeight") );
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mPET6/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `jQuery` `scrollTop` method to set the scroll position of any container. Try this

```
$("elementSelector").scrollTop(valueToScroll);
```

Since you want to scroll to the end of the content try this

```
$("elementSelector").scrollTop($("elementSelector").innerHeight());
```

Comment: If it is scrolling to the top that means the value which you are passuing to `scrollTop` method is not correct. For you to test hard code some value and then see it should scroll down.